# In Eclipse, is it possible to find all methods in project that take a certain parameter type?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

So that's basically my question.  I'm converting all methods  ArrayLists to HashMaps in parameterized methods, but I don't want to convert all ArrayLists to HashMaps since there are a few that are used locally. This is more of a curiosity than anything, but it would be useful.

So, in Eclipse, is it possible to find all methods in project that take a certain parameter type?

Comment: I don't think there is any option to do this in eclipse.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or from menu bar <kbd>Search</kbd> - <kbd>Search ...</kbd>, then choose <kbd>Java Search</kbd>:
[image]

Then click Limit To - Match locations (x of 15 selected):
[image]

This should give what you want.

Comment: Beautiful! I'm quite surprised it was actually a feature!