# Java/Eclipse How to get usages of type methods in a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, static-code-analysis

In Eclipse, I can Ctrl+Shift+G (or r-click -> `References-> Workspace`) to get all references to a type (or field etc) in the workspace.

What I need is a way to get a list of all places where *any method* of a given type is used in the workspace. Namely, I'd like to get all calls to methods of type `java.math.BigDecimal`.

Does Eclipse support such a scenario ?

FWIW: I can do something similar for C# code using VS + Resharper:
r-click on type -> `Find Usages Advanced -> Usages of members`.

### Update

Let me rephrase the question, it seems it's not very clear.

I want to find all of my code that calls *any* of BigDecimal's **methods**.
(From this info, I will then manually (?) derive the subset of BigDecimal's public interface that my code is actually using).

Comment: If Eclipse doesn't support it, I wonder if **IntelliJ Idea** does, since it's made by the same company that makes **Resharper**

Comment: You mean `java.math.BigDecimal` should be parameter of those methods?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov no. I want to find where my code calls BigDecimal's methods (actually, I want to see *which* of BigDecimal's methods I'm using, but the former is close enough)

Comment: Turns out I was right, [IntelliJ does support it](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/find-usages-class-options.html), and it's strikingly familiar to the Resharper feature:  : Find -> Class -> Usages of methods.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this what you want, but found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11836545/1360074

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or from menu bar <kbd>Search</kbd> - <kbd>Search ...</kbd>, then choose <kbd>Java Search</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Cool stuff. So many "hidden" eclipse features. And.. that image uses.. Comic Sans D:

Comment: Nice, but not what I need. This gives a subset of the uses of the BigDecimal *type*. I want the uses of BigDecimal's *methods*

Answer (score 2):

Like the other answers, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> is what you are looking for, but, try to do that with the cursor over the class name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think eclipse support this. At max you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to get call hierarchy of single method.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you may use Ctrl+Alt+H while cursor is on the method name. That will bring you Call Hierarchy view.

Comment: That would work for *one* of (say) BigDecimal's methods. I want to find out all calls to *any of* BigDecimal's methods.