# How to find references to a Spring converter in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring, converters

I'm working on a Java web app which utilises Spring's [ConversionService API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-ConversionService-API).

[Converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html)s look like this:

```
public class MyCustomConverter implements Converter<MySourceClass, MyTargetClass> {
    @Override
    public MyTargetClass convert(final MySourceClass source) {
        // ...conversion code...
        return myTargetClass;
    }
}
```

and are registered in the application config, e.g:

```
@PostConstruct
public void addConverters() {
    genericConversionService.addConverter(myCustomConverter);
    // ...others...
}
```

A conversion can then be applied like this:

```
MyTargetClass result = conversionService.convert(mySource, MyTarget.class);
```

The problem I'm having is finding usage within the code of a particular converter (such as the example directly above). Am using Eclipse IDE - could anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see all the references made to the method `ConversionService.convert`, you can highlight the `convert` method and use the Eclipse short-cut `Ctrl + Shift + G`. This will search the method inside your entire workspace. To search only in the project, you can right-click on the method and select References > Project.

To restrict the references search with a specific method parameter, see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11836545/1743880.